# How to use WorksheetFunction.max/maxifs to find maximum value in 'column' of multidimensional array

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, max, maxifs

I have a 2-dimensional array in vba and I want to use worksheetfunction.max and worksheetfunction.maxifs to find the maximum value in a 'column' of the array.  I'm aware that I can use a loop to do this, but the dataset is very large and I want to reduce the processing time.  Does anyone know if worksheetfunction.max and worksheetfunction.maxifs can be used in this manner, and if yes, any ideas on the syntax to use?

Answer (score 0):

I ran a simple test timing an array loop against the Max WorksheetFunction on a one-dimensional array.  It seems that their speed is comparable.

You would need to use WorksheetFunction.Index in conjunction with the WorksheetFunction.Max for multi-dimensional arrays.  This would make an array loop clearly faster form multi-dimensional arrays

[image: Test Array Loop Versus Max Function]

### Test Code

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestTimes()
    Dim Max1 As Long, Max2 As Long, results() As Long, n As Long, t1 As Double, t2 As Double
    results = getData

    For n = 1 To 10
        t1 = getWorksheetFunctionMaxTime(results, Max1)
        t2 = getWorksheetFunctionMaxTime(results, Max2)

        Debug.Print "WorksheetFunction Time: "; t1, "Array Loop Time: "; t2, Max1 = Max2
    Next
End Sub


Function getData() As Long()
    Dim results(1 To 10000000) As Long
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To 10000000
        results(r) = r
    Next
    getData = results
End Function

Function getWorksheetFunctionMaxTime(ByRef results() As Long, ByRef Max As Long) As Double
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(results)
    getWorksheetFunctionMaxTime = Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Function

Function getLoopArrayMaxTime(ByRef results() As Long, ByRef Max As Long) As Double
    Dim r As Long, LocalMax As Long
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    For r = 1 To 10000000
        If results(r) > LocalMax Then LocalMax = r
    Next
    Max = LocalMax
    getLoopArrayMaxTime = t
End Function
```

Comment: Hi TinMan, thanks for your insights.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You are calling `getWorksheetFunctionMaxTime` in both runs... no wonder they take the same time ;-)